# Merging multiple tables in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Say I have created 3 tables and populated them like so:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(sn INT PRIMARY KEY, val TEXT);
INSERT INTO t1 (sn, val) VALUES (1,'Bobby');
INSERT INTO t1 (sn, val) VALUES (2,'Fred');
INSERT INTO t1 (sn, val) VALUES (3,'Ann');
```

t1 will look like so

```
sn     val
1      Bobby
2      Fred
3      Ann
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE t2(sn INT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
INSERT INTO t2 (sn, val) VALUES (2,5);
INSERT INTO t2 (sn, val) VALUES (4,72);
INSERT INTO t2 (sn, val) VALUES (5,7);
```

t2 will look like so

```
sn     val
2      5
4      72
5      7
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE t3(sn INT PRIMARY KEY, val TEXT);
INSERT INTO t3 (sn, val) VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO t3 (sn, val) VALUES (5,'B');
INSERT INTO t3 (sn, val) VALUES (7,'C');
INSERT INTO t3 (sn, val) VALUES (9,'D');
```

t3 will look like so

```
sn     val
1      A
5      B
7      C
9      D
```

Now I want to create a new table called "merged" and want it to look like this

```
sn    t1.val    t2.val    t3.val
1     Bobby               A
2     Fred      5           
3     Ann
4               72      
5               7         B
7                         C
9                         D
```

I am using sqlite3 and have tried to use the combination of left join and union but I can only do it for not more than 2 tables. I have lots of these tables and want to join all by their primary key. Your suggestions will be most appreciated and looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION in a subquery to get all `sn` values, then use a bunch of left joins for each base table:

```
CREATE TABLE merged AS
SELECT tAll.sn,
       t1.val,
       t2.val,
       t3.val
FROM (SELECT sn FROM t1
      UNION
      SELECT sn FROM t2
      UNION
      SELECT sn FROM t3) AS tAll
LEFT JOIN t1 ON tAll.sn = t1.sn
LEFT JOIN t2 ON tAll.sn = t2.sn
LEFT JOIN t3 ON tAll.sn = t3.sn
```

Answer (score 0):

Because SQLite doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` support the easiest way to do this is by using the `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` command to combine the datasets like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Result (sn INT PRIMARY KEY, val1 TEXT, val2 INT, val3 TEXT);
--
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Result (sn, val1, val2, val3)
SELECT
   sn
  ,val AS val1
  ,(SELECT val2 FROM Result AS R WHERE R.sn = sn) AS val2
  ,(SELECT val3 FROM Result AS R WHERE R.sn = sn) AS val3
FROM t1;
--
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Result (sn, val1, val2, val3)
SELECT
   sn
  ,(SELECT val1 FROM Result AS R WHERE R.sn = sn) AS val1
  ,val AS val2
  ,(SELECT val3 FROM Result AS R WHERE R.sn = sn) AS val3
FROM t2;
--
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Result (sn, val1, val2, val3)
SELECT
   sn
  ,(SELECT val1 FROM Result AS R WHERE R.sn = sn) AS val1
  ,(SELECT val2 FROM Result AS R WHERE R.sn = sn) AS val2
  ,val AS val3
FROM t3;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle link showing it working:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ddfb7/2/0